# Keycloak 'ID' as an Attribute Release to a Client

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Could the ID for a user be retrieved to be sent as a SAML attribute to a Client?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not work with SAML before but I think that what you want can be done by:

- Go to the Realm where the client is;
- Go to the Client;
- Select Mappers;
- Click on `[Create]`;
- As mapper type chose `Javascript Mapper`;
- In the script type `user.id`
- Fill up the rest accordingly, and click [save];

[image]

As pointed out by [@Jan Garaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348604/jan-garaj) in the comments:

> Script for Javascript Mapper is (already/still) deprecated feature and
> it may be removed in the further Keycloak release.

You can use a `User Property Mapper`:

- Go to the Realm where the client is;
- Go to the Client;
- Select Mappers;
- Click on `[Create]`;
- As mapper type chose `User Property;`
- In the property type `id`
- Fill up the rest accordingly, and click [save];

[image]